# Removing a QGraphicsItem's parent

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, parent, qgraphicsitem

I have a `QGraphicsItem` called `child_item` that is a child of another `QGraphicsItem` called `parent_item`. I need to unparent `child_item` from `parent_item` so that `child_item` has no parent.

But when I try `childItem.setItemParent(None)` my script crashes.

Apparently this is because when you remove a `QGraphicsItem`'s parent in this way the item is returned to Qt...

For now I've just created a `global_parent` `QGraphicsItem` so that if any item needs to be unparented I will simply parent it under the `global_parent` and if a `QGraphicsItem` has the parent `global_parent` my code will act like it doesn't have a parent but I would like a better solution.

Any ideas please?

### Some of my code:

```
POINT_SIZE = 7
class Test_Box(QGraphicsItem):
    # Constants
    WIDTH           = 50 * POINT_SIZE
    HEIGHT          = 13 * POINT_SIZE
    RECT            = QRectF(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    CORNER_RADIUS   = 1.5 * POINT_SIZE


    def __init__(self, position, parent=None):
        super(Test_Box, self).__init__(parent)

        # Settings
        self.setFlags(  self.flags()                            |
                        QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable          |
                        QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable             |
                        QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable           |
                        QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges )
        self.setPos(position)


    def boundingRect(self):
        return Test_Box.RECT


    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        # Draw Box
        brush   = QBrush()
        painter.setBrush(brush) 
        painter.drawRoundedRect(Test_Box.RECT, Test_Box.CORNER_RADIUS, Test_Box.CORNER_RADIUS)



    def itemChange(self, change, variant):
        super(Test_Box, self).itemChange(change, variant)
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemScenePositionHasChanged:
            self.setParentItem(None)
        return QGraphicsItem.itemChange(self, change, variant)
```

Calling setItemParent and setting the item's parent to another item does work though so I'm using a generic parent in the meantime.

Comment: For anyone interested, I just ended up creating a global QGraphicsItem to use as the default parent so if I want to unparent something, I just parent it under the global parent (which is not visible) so it gives the same effect as having no parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that `setParent` is not a typo, then that is your issue. A `QGraphicsItem` has no `setParent` method and that should give you an error. You should rather use [`setParentItem`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html#setParentItem):

```
children.setParentItem(None)
```

**Edit**

I created a test case based on your item:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

POINT_SIZE = 7
class Test_Box(QGraphicsItem):
    # Constants
    WIDTH           = 50 * POINT_SIZE
    HEIGHT          = 13 * POINT_SIZE
    RECT            = QRectF(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    CORNER_RADIUS   = 1.5 * POINT_SIZE


    def __init__(self, position, parent=None):
        super(Test_Box, self).__init__(parent)

        # Settings
        self.setFlags(  self.flags()                            |
                        QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable          |
                        QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable             |
                        QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable           |
                        QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges )
        self.setPos(position)


    def boundingRect(self):
        return Test_Box.RECT


    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        # Draw Box
        brush   = QBrush()
        painter.setBrush(brush) 
        painter.drawRoundedRect(Test_Box.RECT, Test_Box.CORNER_RADIUS, Test_Box.CORNER_RADIUS)



    def itemChange(self, change, variant):
        super(Test_Box, self).itemChange(change, variant)
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemScenePositionHasChanged:
            self.setParentItem(None)
        return QGraphicsItem.itemChange(self, change, variant)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()

        self.item1 = Test_Box(QPointF(0, 0))
        self.item2 = Test_Box(QPointF(20, 20))
        self.item11 = Test_Box(QPointF(10, 5), self.item1)

        self.scene.addItem(self.item1)
        self.scene.addItem(self.item2)

        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)

        self.listItems = QPushButton('list')
        self.listItems.clicked.connect(self.printItems)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.listItems)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def printItems(self):
        for item in self.scene.items():
            print item, item.parentItem()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = Window()
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And it works as expected, but I did find some odd behavior. If I don't keep references for items in the `Window` class, namely if I do the following then the application crashes when I move items.

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()

        item1 = Test_Box(QPointF(0, 0))
        item2 = Test_Box(QPointF(20, 20))
        item11 = Test_Box(QPointF(10, 5), item1)

        self.scene.addItem(item1)
        self.scene.addItem(item2)

        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)

        self.listItems = QPushButton('list')
        self.listItems.clicked.connect(self.printItems)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.listItems)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def printItems(self):
        for item in self.scene.items():
            print item, item.parentItem()
```

I don't actually know what happens but looks like the items are garbage collected, which shouldn't happen since `addItem` would give the ownership to the `scene` and that should keep the items 'alive'. This may be a bug in PyQt, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes it was a typo, thanks. I was actually using setParentItem and that was crashing my script. Using setParent would've just given errors because as you said QGraphicsItem has no setParent function.

Comment: @JaredGlass: Can you post your code (or a small example with the problem)? I can't replicate any crashes. For me, `children.setParentItem(None)` removes the parent as expected.